# How can i substitute variables inside an array in the WebSocketBuffer.h file of loadrunner

Tags: loadrunner, vugen

I have captured a loadrunner script using Web-Http protocol. The website uses websocket internally. So I have the WebsocketCB and WebSocketBuffer files created.
There is a WebSocketSend array where one of the values within the array needs to be modified before sending.

```
char WebSocketSend0[] = "Data: dynamicvalue";
```

I am able to save the dynamic values from another packet to a variable.
But i am not able to substitute it in the above array. I used the following convention for a "test" variable

```
char WebSocketSend0[] = "Data: lr_eval_string("{test}")";
```

But it threw up lots of compilation errors.
Is there anyway i can make the substitution , otherwise i have to write lots of code to modify the array.

Answer (score 0):

You have a function inside of string definition.  I see no way this is a valid set of code for substitution.

Have you considered code which is C compliant?

`char WebSocketSend0[] = lr_eval_string("Data: {test}");`

Pick up a good C Primer.   The Head First, 21 Days and Dummies series are all great books.  I own the 21 Days and Dummies books myself.

Comment: I believe this is not valid either. Try 
`char* WebSocketSend0 = lr_eval_string("Data:{test}");`

Comment: Good point, mismatch on character array and pointer to char.   Change the variable to a pointer and the lr_eval_string() evaluation picks up fine.

Comment: @JamesPulley I am aware that this is not possible in C. Just wanted to know if there are any features in loadrunner which would allow something like that.

Comment: "char *WebSocketSend0 = lr_eval_string("Data: {test}");" Works.  Remember, this is just a string.  It just happens to be defined in a different file.  There is absolutely no reason why you cannot define and use this variable inside of your main action.   Create a character array.  Use sprintf() to seed it with the items you need.  Then use it